# Same ActionEvent for multiple components

Tags: javafx, actionevent

I have a code like this,

```
component1.setOnAction((ActionEvent event) -> {
           for(int i=0; i<=10; i++){
            System.out.println(i);
           }
        });

component2.setOnAction((ActionEvent event) -> {
           for(int i=0; i<=10; i++){
            System.out.println(i);
           }
        });
```

To avoid the duplication of code, am trying something like,

```
component1.setOnAction(action);
component2.setOnAction(action);
```

where,

> action = // how can i define the for loop here.

I tried,

```
 ActionEvent action = new ActionEvent(Source, target);
```

The `ActionEvent` constructor asks for a source and target(which i wasnt quite clear on how to use).

How can i achieve this?

Comment: You can set EventHandler in setOnAction(), not the ActionEvent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `setOnAction()` requires an `EventHandler`, not an `ActionEvent`. Nothing prevents you from defining an `EventHandler` and reusing it for multiple components.

```
EventHandler predefinedHandler = (e) -> {
   for (int i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {
      System.out.println(i);
   }
};

component1.setOnAction(predefinedHandler);
component2.setOnAction(predefinedHandler);
```